# Mouseover event not triggered when data updated in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, d3.js, mouseover

Every element in my `svg` listens to a `mouseover` event, and when an element is clicked the chart would be updated to show another set of elements.

However, if I click an element and a new element occurs right under the mouse, the `mouseover` event is not triggered unless I move the mouse a bit.

Then I found that this problem only occurred in Chrome...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Chrome issue, no workaround.